# iTunes store search from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes-store

When I go to search the iTunes store from my iPhone the page displays a "No Results for"...  I have been unable to find a way to perform another search.  This page is not responding to any input.  What should I do?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Did you try all the usual solutions? Hard reset etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the App Store app by double-clicking the Home button.

If that doesn't cut it, restart the iPhone and try again.